# update-ca-trust not updating /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt on Fedora 37

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a self signed certificate which I wish to trust. Adding it a traditional way is not working - I still have SSL errors in browser and curl. What else am I supposed to do? Fedora 37 x64.

```
[aleksandr@fedora ~]$ sudo cp Downloads/localhost.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
[aleksandr@fedora ~]$ cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/localhost.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDDCCAfSgAwIBAgIITC1dTII92rYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwFDESMBAGA1UE
...
p8TMthJT6UFci8jxS/MYaQtEKbecxc9edoqN7IZKLv06ly8i5AFiEEbfzqL1HBYJ
...
bQnby+pQjSPhcpVsWzzQpA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
[aleksandr@fedora ~]$ sudo update-ca-trust extract
[aleksandr@fedora ~]$ cat /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt | grep p8TMthJT6UFci8jxS
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the certificate I tried to add wasn't CA. That's why `update-ca-trust` didn't do anything.
This can be checked with
`openssl x509 -in localhost.pem -text -noout` with output:

> X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
> CA:FALSE